# Can I use Feign interceptor while calling the feign requisitions with completable future?

Tags: java, spring-boot, completable-future, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I am trying to use the feign interceptor to the feign requisitions i am calling using completable future, but the ServletRequestAttributes only return null.

```
public class FeignInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor  {

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
        ServletRequestAttributes attributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        HttpServletRequest request = attributes.getRequest();
        String bearerToken = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
        requestTemplate.header(AUTHORIZATION, bearerToken);
    }
}
```

```
    public Object searchObject() {
        Object[] listFutures;
        try {
            listFutures = Stream.of(getObjectFuture1(), getObjectFuture2(), getObjectFuture3())
                    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                    .toArray(Object[]::new);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw e.getCause();
        }

        // Rest of the code

        return listFutures[0];
    }
    
    private CompletableFuture<Object> getObjectFuture1() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> feignClient.detailObject(null));
    }
    
    private CompletableFuture<Object> getObjectFuture2() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> feignClient.listObject(true));
    }
    
    private CompletableFuture<Object> getObjectFuture3() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> feignClient.listObject(true));
    }
```

I'm looking for an anwser for a long time but couldn't find it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.